# Error occured while running script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I am using QGIS version 2.18.9. I first create a graphical modeler and it is working. Then I export it to python script. While I am running the script I got following error massage.

> "NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem** See log for more detail".

Can you explain the reason?

My script is shown below:

```
##Testing=name
##drawingdxf=file
##cleanf=output vector
outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.in.dxf',drawingdxf,'1',True,False,True,False,False,True,['200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000'],0,None)
outputs_GRASS7V_CLEAN_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.clean', outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1['output'],1,0.1,['200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000'],-1.0,0.0001,cleanf,None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because of points in variable name. Variable name doesn't include points. Try to change `outputs_GRASS7V.IN.DXF_1` into `outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1` or something else without points.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I tried it ,but it doesn't work

Comment: At least, I guess, you are getting different error, aren't you?

Comment: I created another model and follow your advice.Yes,It is working.Thanks a lot for your comment.Now I further developed my script.Now I am getting another error called "NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__".I have edited my question already.You can see my developed script above.I highly appreciate if you can help me further.